# React Native Enumerable key on prototype chain error

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, expo

Im trying to upload an base64 image to the Firebase Storage with and getting this error:

> One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. Are you trying to assign a prototype property? We don't allow it, as this is an edge case that we do not support.

Running on EXPO@19.0.0 (same problem on v18) and React@16.0.0-alpha.12 (which comes with Expo v19).

The function im using is the following
source: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/expo-rn-firebase-image-upload/blob/master/README.md

```
const addSignService = (signData, imageAsBase64, filename) => {        
  _uploadAsByteArray(convertToByteArray(imageAsBase64), filename, (progress) => {
    console.log('_uploadAsByteArray callback '+progress);
    //this.setState({ progress })
  });
}

const _uploadAsByteArray = async (pickerResultAsByteArray, filename, progressCallback) => {
  console.log('_uploadAsByteArray');
  try {

    var metadata = {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    };

    var ref = storageRef.child('images/'+ firebaseAuth().currentUser.uid + '/' + filename);
    console.log('before upload');

    let uploadTask = ref.put(pickerResultAsByteArray, metadata);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {

      progressCallback && progressCallback(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)

      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      console.log('log test');

    }, function (error) {
      console.log("in _uploadAsByteArray ", error);

    }, function () {
      console.log('function');
      var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      console.log("_uploadAsByteArray ", uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL)

    });
  } catch (ee) {
    console.log("when trying to load _uploadAsByteArray ", ee)
  }
}

const convertToByteArray = (input) => {
  console.log('convertToByteArray');

  var binary_string = atob(input);

  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes
}

const atob = (input) => {
  console.log('atob');

  const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

  let str = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
  let output = '';

  if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
    throw new Error("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");
  }
  for (let bc = 0, bs = 0, buffer, i = 0;
    buffer = str.charAt(i++);

    ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
      bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
  ) {
    buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
  }

  return output;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the React Native / iOS Remote Debugger is activated while calling `Firebase.put()` this error is coming up. Deactivating the debugger resolved the error and the function is working fine.

Thanks to aaronksaunders on Github for the help.
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/expo-rn-firebase-image-upload/issues/3

Comment: Just saved me from a rabbit hole. Thanks!!